# Creating a global function, accessible from all classes, with Python + Pylons

Tags: python, pylons

Using pylons 0.9.7, I'm trying to make a function that connects to a database on demand.   I'd like it to be accessible from all functions within all model classes.

In `model/__init__.py`, I have:

```
#Establish an on-demand connection to the central database
def connectCentral():
    engine = engine_from_config(config, 'sqlalchemy.central.')
    central.engine = engine
    central.Session.configure(bind=engine)
```

This function is accessible everywhere.  However, when I try to run it from within a class specified in `model/class.py`, it returns:

```
NameError: global name 'connectCentral' is not defined
```

Do I have to do any kind of special import?  Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
from model import connectCentral
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you done `import init` ? Or rather `from init import connectCentral`?

If you did, that such name should be defined. If not, you can try writing `global connectCentral` in method's body, but I believe it is only for using global variables.

Are you sure, this modules is supposed to have name **init.py** rather than **__init__.py**? Could you post some more code, where you are trying to use your function?

**EDIT**

So you are having `__init__.py`, fine. Are you doing import `from model import connectCentral`? Don't you have any circural imports (like import from `__init__.py` in `class.py` and import from `class.py` in `__init__.py`)?

Comment: Hi -- I'm trying to use my function in a class called model/user.py.  I believe __init__.py is correct as this is how pylons created the default template.  It works when I do import __init__.